# React Native change stylesheets base on orientation change

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is there a better way to change the stylesheet based on the device orientation. My current code works button wanted to know if there is a cleaner way to do the same. My stylesheet elements have the same properties just different values

```
<View style={orientation ? stylesPortrait.volumeFaderWrapper : stylesLandscape.volumeFaderWrapper}>
    <Text>Hello World</Text>
    ...
</View>

const stylesPortrait = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    // placeholder. leave style property. Its not in use in portrait view
  },
  volumeFaderWrapper: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  volumeSlider: {
    flex: 3,
  },
  volumeText: {
    flex: 2,
    textAlign: 'justify',
  },
  muteBtn: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  muteBtnLabel: {
    fontSize: 10,
  },
});

const stylesLandscape = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 2,
  },
  volumeFaderWrapper: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: 9,
  },
  volumeSlider: {
    flex: 3,
  },
  volumeText: {
    flex: 2,
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
  muteBtn: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  muteBtnLabel: {
    fontSize: 10,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base style object and make use of the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Relevant information and example from [mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals)

> The Rest/Spread Properties for ECMAScript proposal (ES2018) added spread properties to object literals. It copies own enumerable properties from a provided object onto a new object.

```
let obj1 = { foo: 'bar', x: 42 };
let obj2 = { foo: 'baz', y: 13 };

let clonedObj = { ...obj1 };
// Object { foo: "bar", x: 42 }

let mergedObj = { ...obj1, ...obj2 };
// Object { foo: "baz", x: 42, y: 13 }
```

So in your specific example you could do something like this:

```
const baseStyles = {
  volumeFaderWrapper: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  volumeSlider: {
    flex: 3,
  },
  volumeText: {
    flex: 2,
  },
  muteBtn: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  muteBtnLabel: {
    fontSize: 10,
  },
}

const stylesLandscape = StyleSheet.create({
  ...baseStyles,
  container: {
    flex: 2,
  },
  volumeFaderWrapper: {
    padding: 9
  },
  volumeText: {
    textAlign: 'right'
  },
});

// Apply the same idea to stylesPortrait
```